# How to use java to identify user key stroke

Tags: java, client

I am learning Java Networking and threading, and want to write a java program that acts as Client and Server at the same time. 
The concept is simple:

```
One Server thread receives messages.
One client thread send messages.
```

However, I want to simulate a very common feature in IM applications, which is while you are typing, the other end of a conversation would see "the user is typing". I am still learning, but I think if swing is used,this would be easy. Just wondering if a pure command line interface is used, is this still doable with Java? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Java doesn't have very good console control so I doubt you would be able to implement a "the user is typing" feature if you were to go down that route. I would suggest you learn swing (or similar) and use that for the client application.

Comment: Yeah, That's what I suspect as well